# javascript listener wrapper function - removeListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code as a wrapper function for listeners and when I remove a listener I want to execute the callback - I have to use this "callback()" instead of just callback inside removeEventListener callback parameter. Could someone have a look and see what I'm doing wrong

when I think it should be just 
el.removeEventlistener(event, callback, capture)

but this works instead which i think is wrong
el.removeEventlistener(event, callback(), capture)

UPDATED:

```
var evts = (function () {
  'use strict';

  var listeners = [],
      add,
      remove;

  add = function (evt, elem, fn, capture) {
    var callback = function (evt) {      
      fn.call(elem, evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
    };

    listeners.push({
      evt: evt,
      elem: elem,
      fn: fn,
      callback: callback,
      capture, capture,
      removed: false
    });

    if (elem.addEventListener) {
      elem.addEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
      elem.attachEvent('on' + evt, callback, capture);
    } else {
      elem['on' + evt] = callback;
    }
  };

  remove = function (evt, elem, fn, capture) {

    var callback = function (evt) {      
      fn.call(elem, evt, evt && evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement);
    };

    callback();

    listeners.forEach(function (obj, i) {
      if (obj.evt === evt && obj.elem === elem && 
          !obj.removed) {
        obj.removed = true;
        callback = obj.callback;
        listeners.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });

    if (elem.removeEventListener) {
      elem.removeEventListener(evt, callback, capture);
    } else if (elem.detachEvent) {
      elem.detachEvent('on' + evt, callback, capture);
    } else {
      elem['on' + evt] = null;
    }
  };

  return {
    add: add,
    remove: remove
  };
}());
```

Comment: It's definitely not removing the listener when you do `callback()`. Do you really need an IE7 polyfill?

Comment: is the ie7 polyfill the atach event and detach

Comment: or is it elem['on' + evt]

Comment: The attach/detach. The onevent is for far older or more obscure implementations.

Comment: Technically IE8 would need the attach/detach fix too, but I'd rather implement it as an prototype extension.

Comment: I can remove those if need be but that's not the problem

Comment: If you remove the polyfills, the there's no longer a need for the wrapper, which is the problem. But ultimately, you should be using the `obj.callback` from the cached object to do the removal. No need to create another `callback` when doing the removal.

Comment: that's exactly what I ended up doing but for off() function I added it's own callback excutable to run and it works - so you have a goodby function to execute have a look at my code now - does it make sense

Comment: this could be a problem if your code allows listeners to be bound more than once. `callback = obj.callback;`

Comment: And this does nothing: `listeners.slice(i, 1);`

Comment: why is slice not doing anything - how to remedy that

Comment: It returns a subslice of `listeners`, which you're just discarding.

Comment: it was splice that was needed sorry

Comment: How would I handle eventListeners that can be bound more than once can you help write something for me

Comment: You'd search to see if the event-type/capture-setting/function combination has already bound, and if so, don't bind it again. First question should be what browsers you're hoping to support. There do exist polyfills of this type, so you may want to consider that too